# Can you explain to me the workings of the phrasal verb "vector in" in the sentence "The insurgents are already vectoring in from the east"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I think I sorta understood the meaning of it (or maybe I didn't), but I'd still rather a clear definition.

This sentence is composed by the very first words in the short story [The Colonel](https://www.tor.com/2014/07/29/the-colonel-peter-watts/), in case some more context is needed.

Thank you for taking the time to read my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics a vector is a line having both direction and distance, but in aeronautics it is used to identify the course, or series of courses, that an airplane should follow to reach a point, often an airport. To "vector in" is to follow directions describing a route (which may consist of multiple changes of direction) to a destination.

Answer (score 0):

This use of "vector" perhaps comes from physics.  Where a "vector" can tell you both speed and direction of something that is moving.